# LDAP: error code 50 - The entry uid=test@info.com,ou=People,o=Drive,dc=company,dc=com cannot be added due to insufficient access rights

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to add account to OpenDS running of windows.
I am using spring, opends2.2.1, hibernate and Jboss 5.1
When I tried to add the user, I get the following errors.

```
javax.faces.FacesException: #{user.save}: org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Operation failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoPermissionException: [LDAP: error code 50 - The entry uid=test@info.com,ou=People,o=Drive,dc=company,dc=com cannot be added due to insufficient access rights]; remaining name 'uid=test@info.com, ou=People, o=Drive'
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the `password-reset` privilege to useradmin (or to the user you try to change password with):

See: https://backstage.forgerock.com/#!/docs/opendj/3/admin-guide#about-privileges

> "For example, in order to reset user's passwords, an administrator
>   needs both the `password-reset` privilege and also access control to
>   write `userPassword` values on the user entries."

Answer (score 0):

1. Please verify that the LDAP directory was configured with the proper
   permissions as in Connecting to an LDAP Directory.
2. This error is a permissions configuration issue on the LDAP side
3. Your LDAP administrator will need to grant the LDAP bind user the
   permissions required to edit attributes.Exactly how this is set will vary depending on what type of LDAP server you are using.
4. LDAP users, groups and memberships are retrieved from your directory server. When you modify a user, group or membership via the application administration screens, the changes will be applied directly to your LDAP directory server. Please ensure that the LDAP user specified for the application has modification permissions on your LDAP directory server.

I hope my answer is useful in your case. Because as per the logs it says you are facing permission issue while modifying the LDAP entry.

Comment: Thanks Rahul Wagh for replay me, we tried but we couldn't solve this error please help us.

Comment: Could you please check with the Active Directory Admin .....whether they have granted permission to you OR the user which you have configured in the code to get the details from the LDAP directory....because i faced this issue so contacted ADMIN of ldap to ask whether i have permission to view the details of Active directory or not......so later Admin provided me the access right...

Comment: Thanks Rahuk Wagh for the replay, we will try and let you know if any errors.